# how can you configure spring to execute overlapping fixedRate tasks?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring

i am trying to execute a task at a fixed rate using the @Scheduled annotation in java spring.  however, it seems that by default spring will not execute a fixedRate task at a fixed rate if the task is slower than the rate. is there some setting i can add to my spring configuration to change this behavior?

**example**:

```
@Service
public class MyTask{
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
    public void doIt(){
        // this sometimes takes >1000ms, in which case the next execution is late
        ...
    }
}
```

i have a **work-around**, but it seems less than ideal. basically, i just replace the default single-thread executor with a thread pool, then i have a scheduled method call an async method since the @Async annotation allows concurrent executions:

```
@Service
public class MyTask{
    @Async
    public void doIt(){
        // this sometimes takes >1000ms, but the next execution is on time
        ...
    }
}

@Service
public class MyTaskScheduler{
    ...
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
    public void doIt(){
        myTask.doIt();
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
public class MySpringJavaConfig{
    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public Executor taskScheduler() {
        return Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);
    }
}
```

boring details of my **real-world scenario**: in my production code i have a task that takes between 10ms and 10 minutes depending on the current workload.  ideally, i would like to capture a new thread from the pool every 1000ms so that the number of concurrent threads increases with the workload. obviously i have an upper limit on threads in place (among other controls) to keep things from getting out of hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`TaskScheduler`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/TaskScheduler.html#scheduleAtFixedRate-java.lang.Runnable-java.util.Date-long-) API (which backs some of the Spring Scheduling behavior) seems to be defined to prevent the behavior you are requesting

> Schedule the given `Runnable`, invoking it at the specified execution
>   time and subsequently with the given period.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> - **period** the interval between successive executions of the task (in milliseconds)

*subsequently* and *successive* seem to indicate that the next execution will only occur after the current execution is complete.

What's more, [`ScheduledExecutorService#scheduleAtFixedRate(..)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/TaskScheduler.html#scheduleAtFixedRate-java.lang.Runnable-java.util.Date-long-) (which the built-in `TaskScheduler` implementations use) also says

> If any execution of this task takes longer than its period, then
>   subsequent executions may start late, **but will not concurrently
>   execute**.

So there's another layer of the implementation that prevents the behavior you want.

A possible solution, and one I don't recommend since the API doesn't seem to be built around it, is to define and provide your own `TaskScheduler` that does run the task concurrently. Look into [`@EnableScheduling`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableScheduling.html) and [`SchedulingConfigurer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/SchedulingConfigurer.html) for how to register a `TaskScheduler`.

Comment: i appreciate the references, and am investigating the SchedulingConfigurer and cron pattern based jobs. that said, i disagree with your interpretation of "subsequently" and "successive", and would like a solution (however awkward) that accomplishes my goal. as such, i intent to wait a bit longer before accepting this answer in the hopes that someone can come up with a specific functional spring configuration.

Answer (score 2):

the best solution i have found so far is to simply use a delegate to make the method calls async. this is only preferable because it allows me to declare the schedule in the same class as the method which does the work:

```
@Service
public class AsyncRunner {
    @Async
    public void run(Runnable runnable) {
        runnable.run();
    }
}

@Service
public class MyTask{
    ...
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
    public void scheduleIt(){
        asyncRunner.run(this::doIt);
    }
    public void doIt(){
        // this sometimes takes >1000ms, but the next execution is on time
        ...
    }
}
```