# Spring cron expression - is really a cron?

Tags: java, spring, cron, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to replicate the Linux cron in Spring scheduling with cron expression.

I want to run my task for every 10 seconds and below is my code sample.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0/10 * * * * *")
public void task() throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("Scheduler started!!!" + new Date());
    Thread.sleep(60000);
}
```

I added `Thread.sleep(60000)` purposefully because my task can take longer time to process.

What I expected from above code is that the task will run for every 10 seconds but it is not. The delay in executing the next task was 1 min 10 seconds.

Below is the output which I got:

```
Scheduler started!!!Tue May 08 21:15:50 GMT+05:30 2018
Scheduler started!!!Tue May 08 21:17:00 GMT+05:30 2018
```

What I see is the behavior is exactly same as java's `Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate`.

How the spring cron expression is different than java's Timer? Is there any possibility that it can work as Linux cron - Meaning, though the previous task was running, start the new task?

Comment: This might be useful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30313277/how-can-you-configure-spring-to-execute-overlapping-fixedrate-tasks/30335656 -- Spring Scheduler will not execute the same task concurrently, so if your job is still running, it will skip executions until it's done.

Comment: Is there any way that I can make it run as Linux cron?

Comment: Since you already have Spring, I'd say wrap your scheduled task up in a REST endpoint and call it using `curl`.

Comment: Use another thread to run the expensive operation and don’t wait for the result

Comment: @baao, got you... Using worker thread will solve the problem. Thanks!!

Comment: Oh yeah, that would work. To go with @baao's line of logic, you could also use Spring's `@Async` stuff to do that for you as well.

Comment: Spring by default uses a single threaded executor. If you pause it (`Thread.sleep`) you pause the whole scheduler. Configure a `TaskScheduler` with multiple threads (like the `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler`) to have concurrent executing tasks or simply make the method `@Async` next to `@Scheduled` and make sure you have a `TaskExecutor` with multiple threads (by default it is using the `SyncTaskExecutor` reusing the caller thread).

Comment: Did you try using fixedRate for @Scheduled annotation?

Comment: @M.Deinum Do you mind posting an answer based on your comment?

Answer (score 0):

Use `*/10` instead of `0/10`. Source : https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html

Comment: Still that doesn't work. Basically I wanted to make it as Linux cron. Even after changing as you suggested, I got the same output. If the previous task is running then it won't spawn the new task.

Comment: I'm suspicious about `Thread.sleep(60000);` , it may freeze your thread so the `@Scheduled` is also affected. Not sure about this.. Maybe try to loop on something heavy to simulate instead of using `Thread.sleep()`.

Comment: It seems that @Ivan got what you wanted ;)

Comment: Nevermind, Seems Linux cron cannot be achieved. Worker threads will solve the problem