# How to execute a single scheduled task concurrently in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

Is it possible to use SpringBoot Scheduling Tasks to execute the same task in multiple threads at the same time? My task needs to be executed every 10 seconds, but it could take more than 30 seconds. I know that using ThreadPoolTaskScheduler is a good way to run multiple Scheduling Tasks at the same time. I tried that way, but it did not work in my case.

My code is as follows.

```
@Component
public class CronTask {
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CronTask.class);

    @Scheduled(cron="0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * *")
    public void execute1() throws InterruptedException {
        logger.info("execute1 start");
        Thread.sleep(30 * 1000);
        logger.info("execute1 end");
    }
}
```

The configuration is as follows.

```
@Configuration
public class ScheduleConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        taskScheduler.setPoolSize(2);
        return taskScheduler;
    }
}
```

The result is as follows.

```
18:21:20.009  INFO 5324 --- [taskScheduler-1] CronTask   : execute1 start
18:21:50.021  INFO 5324 --- [taskScheduler-1] CronTask   : execute1 end
18:22:00.015  INFO 5324 --- [taskScheduler-1] CronTask   : execute1 start
```

Comment: Add `@Async` to the `@SCheduled` method and add ` @EnableAsync` to the configuration.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30335656/4655324

Comment: I was able to get the desired behavior by using ```@Async``` and ```@EnableAsync```. Thank you very much.